# Tests dir is missing in my project

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I (Git) pulled my (working) project on a different pc (on both pc's I'm working with Intellij-idea), I (Maven) compiled it but my tests directory is out of sync.
Trying to run it I get "*0 test class found in package ''*".

Ideas?

Comment: And yes, I tried to clean, compile, install (and what not), but it did not help.

Comment: What do you mean by `out of sync` ? Have you pushed the classes ? Worked on a different branch?

Comment: It means that although I have my Tests dir up and running on my main pc, Intellij could not recognize it on my other pc. Thus, I cannot run the tests and cannot run coverage...

Comment: Are the test classes actually there on your other PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the Tests directory was not in the same hierarchy as my code.
The environment on my first pc was configured so it will bypass the issue and just run the tests as they are, but it is only a local bandage.
So if you come across a problem of that sort, first make sure that you have the same hierarchy level (code and tests), otherwise Maven will not find and run the tests.